# Rest API response XML

Tags: web-services, rest

I am developing a rest api for compiling the given code and sending the output.
how should i structure the xml file ? I mean the output can generate many lines.

thanks

Answer (score -2):

Well first, you should make sure there are some less than signs, like this one: < Feel free to take it, I don't need it myself, I can make more.

Then you'll need a word like, I dunno, code. After that word you'll need to put a larger than sign, and of course, I have one here for you to take: >, so ahead, copy and paste it if you need.

After that, you should output your code.

Finally, you should put one of these at the end: , then that's all.. You've made a structured xml file. :D

Comment: is it okay to send multiple lines in a single xml tag ?

Comment: Is it OK to write multiple lines in XHTML? :D Remember, valid XHTML is valid XML, so you can do anything in XML that you can do in XHTML.